# LifeCycleExecutionException : Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT:run

Tags: java, angular, spring, spring-boot, maven

I found a great project on GitHub https://github.com/zhulinn/SpringBoot-Angular7-Online-Shopping-Store.
But when I tried to run this on my pc, I got many errors(followed the steps provided in the link itself).
Somehow I was able to run frontend but I am facing issues running the backend part. I am very new to java, spring and angular. I will be really grateful if someone can please help me set up this project on my pc. Getter and setter methods were missing which I added **User.java**.
**Even very basic mistakes could have been done by me.** ***Thank you in advance.***
**Attached a log file** - https://paste.ee/p/8YuG4

[Latest error I am facing while executing the backend part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgB12.jpg)

Comment: Why are you using a SNAPSHOT version?

Comment: I believe you've done changes to the original project, correct? Can you provide the full build log. (Attach a file instead of the screen shot.) Can't see the failure reason from the attached

Comment: @khmarbaise it was the way the project was initially built so I tried to change the version by changing values in the <version> tag but the error remained the same. Even tried mvn update.

Comment: @NipunThathsara How to create a build log, since errors are displayed only in the command prompt.

Comment: In Ubuntu `mvn clean install > log.out` and attach the `log.out` file once done.

Comment: @NipunThathsara I have added the links of the 2 logs before and after the plug in.   <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.19.1</version>
 </plugin>                                                                                                                                              This plugin seems to make the BUILD run successfully. I suspect a server connection issue.